# Combine two views in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am new to Drupal 8. I have a view with exposed filter which filters content based on a taxonomy. This is called 'filter by category' and shows a dropdown.

I have another view with contextual filter that shows an index with A-Z. This A-Z is generated with first letter of content title. When user clicks on each letter, view filters all contents with that letter and displays it. This view is called 'filter by index' and shows index list.

Requirement is to show 'Filter by category' and 'Filter by index' as dropbox  one below other and results should appear below dropboxes and index.

Since both of these are two different views, i am not sure on how to achieve it. any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask why are you using 2 different views for this? are they both showing the same content? if so: i think you can achieve this with one view
- In the (filter by index) view , add the Taxonomy as a relationship in the advanced section 
- once you add that taxonomy as a relationship, you can then add the taxonomy filter to the filters area 
- then you will have the 2 filters in one block

[image: screenshot].